# docker build error

Tags: php, ubuntu, docker

```
E: Release file for http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 9h 35min 49s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Полистал первые 2 страницы в гугле с этой проблемой, ничего не помогло. Ждать 9 часов не вариант =(

Comment: Поменять на другое зеркало не пробовал? На тот же Яндекс.

Comment: Вот почему, если ошибка не понятна ее прям целиком суют в гуголллл..... читайте внимательнее и подчеркните для себя суть  проблемы - как писали выше замена зеркал первая идея

Comment: @Beeen007 как их заменить, это в конфиге докера от php:7.3-fpm, но я уже заменил на php:7.3-fpm-stretch